# Logarithmic integral

Tags: integration

I am trying to find the following integral:

$$\int \ln(Ax)~\ln(Bx)~dx$$

I can't really think of a way to find it so please just give me a hint and I will do the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should use the fact that $\ln(Ax)=\ln A + \ln x$. Your integral simplifies to
$$\begin{eqnarray}\int \ln (Ax) \ln (Bx) dx &=& \int (\ln A + \ln x) (\ln B + \ln x) dx \\ &=& \ln A \ln B \int dx + \left(\ln A + \ln B \right) \int \ln x dx + \int \left(\ln x\right)^2 dx \end{eqnarray}$$
Use integration by parts to evaluate $\int \ln x dx$ and $\int \left(\ln x\right)^2 dx$. You can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$\ln(Ax)=\ln A+\ln x$ and then let $\ln x=t$. Integration by parts will give the result.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \ln(Ax)\ln(Bx) dx=\ln(Ax)(x\ln(Bx)-x)-\int(x\ln(Bx)-x)\frac{A}{x}dx$$